# How to set data limit to a metered wlan?

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

For Android 7, we can set a WLAN (wifi connection network) to a metered WLAN, which work similar like a cellular network.

For cellular network, we are able to set data limit.

So, the question is, how do we set data limit to a metered WLAN?

Comment: If not supported in your ROM already, you may need a third-party app

Comment: Which device/ROM are you using?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Checked my device and could not find an option to set data limit, would like to know which third-party app able to set data limit in general for android 7.x nougat phones. Thanks.